# Page builder editing not saving

Tags: admin, admin-panel, patches, page-builder

I am using the Magento version 2.4.3 P1, In the latest chrome version the changes are not applied when we are tying to save in the page builder.

I applied this patch ACSD-48857_2.2.3-p1.patch but not worked.
I also turn off JS minification.
Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this patch, it should fix your problem https://github.com/mirasvit/module-blog/issues/162